# Xcode / Working for a completely distinct application but parallely to another one

Tags: applications, xcode, apple-id

I used to work on my own mobile application through my Apple Id, tied to my own mail address.

**Now, I am working for a company aiming to build their application.**
In order to correctly put the application build on my iPhone device in development mode, must I completely use a different Apple Id, meaning tied to my mail inside the company?

To put in a nutshell, how to work parallely for distinct companies with Xcode?

Note: Using my own Macbook Pro device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if i misunderstood your question. You want to work in a machine with different developer account. Yes you can.

Go to **Xcode>Preferences>Accounts** and sign in with as much developer id you want to use. Make sure that you have all the certificate, public key and privet key pair in your Mac Keychain. [For details you can refer this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Next time when you work on an app in Xcode please choose the **team** from **target settings** [image]